# Can't use custom font in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uifont, custom-font

I'm trying to use custom font for my iOS app. Here is what I do

I added my custom font (m.tff) to Xcode Supporting files directory. Also I create entry called Fonts provided by application with value name of the font (m.tff) in myApp.plist

In my view I have a label

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRect(10, 20, 230, 30)];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"My custom font" size:15];
```

etc...

The problem is that when I launch the app the text in label is with default font instead of using the specific one.

What I miss here ?

EDITED

Well it seem works now, but the font applies only for characters like , ? but not for letters.
I'm using cyrillic btw.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this to get all the fonts available

```
  // List all fonts on iPhone
  NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
  for(NSString *familyName in familyNames)
  {
    NSLog(@"family: %@", familyName);

    NSArray *fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]];
    for(NSString *fontName in fontNames)
    {
      NSLog(@"    font: %@", fontName);
    }
  }
```

Look for the font you embedded and see if it is the name is the same.

Answer (score 4):

Font extension should be ttf instead of tiff

and then make an entry in plist

Fonts provided by application   Font.ttf

Comment: The O.P. has now edited his question to change `.tiff` to `.tff` (which is *still incorrect*).  It may be that Luke's answer is the most appropriate one now.

Comment: yes it is incorrect it should be ttf (true type font) instead of tff

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if your `[UIFont fontWithName:@"My font" size:15]` line returns a UIFont object that is not null.

Comment: and yes, I like @Piyush's answer as well.  +1 to him.

Comment: Edited my answer as you edited your question, you sneaky guy.  :-) My original question pointed out a spelling error in your copied & pasted code.

Answer (score 2):

In your Info.plist file, add the key: `Fonts provided by application` with an array object, and set the items of the array to strings as follows:

```
MyFont.ttf
```

Where `MyFont` is the EXACT name as listed for the font in your Mac's app, "Font Book." Use Spotlight to launch font book and then find your font file in there to double check the name.

Then when you set the font to your label:

```
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"MyFont" size: someFloatValue];
```

Comment: Does your font file contain the characters you are trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

m.tiff doesn't sound like a supported font file, i.e. TrueType or OpenType.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your fonts are in info.plist (Fonts provided by application)
2. Select yor target, in the build phases tab, Copy Bundle Resources, add your fonts.