# Custom font is not added to project

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uifont, custom-font

I have the same issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053597/cant-use-custom-font-in-ios-app)

I have a font called ANTIQUAA.TTF. This font is added to Supporting Files of the project.
In my app plist I have entry Fonts provided by application and ANTIQUAA.TTF is added there.

I can't use this font in the app. When I run this method I can't see the font.

```
 NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
    NSArray *fontNames;
    NSInteger indFamily, indFont;
    for (indFamily=0; indFamily<[familyNames count]; ++indFamily)
    {
        NSLog(@"Family name: %@", [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]);
        fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
                     [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:
                      [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]]];
        for (indFont=0; indFont<[fontNames count]; ++indFont)
        {
            NSLog(@"    Font name: %@", [fontNames objectAtIndex:indFont]);
        }
        [fontNames release];
    }
    [familyNames release];
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Possible (but sort of like a meta-)duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application

Answer (score 4):

push the add button in "Copy Bundle Resources" and click on the font files.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just need to add the font resource to your .plist file.

Open your plist as text and paste:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
        <string>ANTIQUAA.TTF</string>
</array>
```

Comment: You probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: I check that after your suggestion.

Comment: Hmmm. Sometimes the listed font name is actually different than the font filename. Are you sure it is not listed as something different?

Comment: I'm sure. Curious fact is that I can use only one font as a custom. I have tried tens of fonts.