# Unable to import custom font into XCode

Tags: ios, uifont

I am trying to import a custom font into XCode and have followed the below steps:

1. Added the TTF file to my project under "Supporting Files"
2. Added the TTF file under UIAppFonts array in the PList file
3. In the ViewController, I have tried to print out the list of available fonts using the below code - `NSLog(@"FONT FAMILIES\n%@",[UIFont familyNames]);`

However, the specific font does not appear to have been added to my project. This has me stumped. Can anyone shed some light on what the problem could be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom font is not added to project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649436/custom-font-is-not-added-to-project)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can not include .ttf font into project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447558/can-not-include-ttf-font-into-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution - the solution was provided in the answer here - [Custom font is not imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649436/custom-font-is-not-added-to-project)

Comment: also see this link..it helped me, hope it helps U. http://sugartin.info/2011/07/25/load-and-access-custom-fonts/