# Can not include .ttf font into project

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, xcode4.5

I am trying to include the font "Hipchick" into my project but it does not work. I have tested a few methods and ended up with this one: [iOS tips: Custom Fonts](http://refactr.com/blog/2012/09/ios-tips-custom-fonts/) to try to solve this but it still doesn't work.

Here is some screens and code:

[image]

The font is added to the project: "hitch__.ttf"

[image]

It is added to the .plist.

[image]

It is in the bundle.

[image]

Here is the info about the font.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

NSLog(@"hipch___: %@",[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Hipchick"]);



testLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hipchick" size:30];
testLbl.text = @"Frank Zappa";
}
```

I have tried "Hipchick", "hipchick" and "hitch__" but it still display the wrong font.

I would really appreciate any help possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is Step for, How to add custom font in Application.

1 - Add `.TTF` font in your application
2 - Modify the `application-info.plist file`.
3 - Add the key **"Fonts provided by application"** to a new row
4 - and add each `.TTF` file (of font) to each line.

[image]

For more info read [This](http://www.developers-life.com/how-to-include-ttf-fonts-to-ios-app.html) and [This](http://www.waterworld.com.hk/en/node/157) site.

> FOR MOREINFORMATION :

But after adding font to your application, you need to apply/write real name of your font, so check [How do I get the font name from an otf or ttf file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788330/how-do-i-get-the-font-name-from-an-otf-or-ttf-file)