# Font usable in Windows but not in iOS

Tags: ios, uifont

I am making an app that writes/plays byzantine music and I 'd like to port it to iOS.
For that I 've been using a family of fonts that work well under windows, and also FontCreator does not show a problem with them.

However, under iOS, they do load ok with UIFont* but they are not usable, that is, when I type the character '1', the '1' in system font is displayed instead of that font.

What could be wrong?

For reference, I 've attached the font: http://www.michaelchourdakis.com/temp/ez.ttf .

Note that the font isn't loaded in the Font Book as well. So there must be a problem in the font.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447558/can-not-include-ttf-font-into-project

Comment: Νο, I 've already added it to the plist and the UIFont is indeed created (it is not nil). However this very font does not also load into the Font Book in OSX.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be something wrong with your font. If you try install it on Mac OS (Mavericks), it shows following errors:

- EZ Psaltica

  - 'name' table usability
  - 'sfnt' required tables
  - 'name' table structure

I guess iOS has the same problem when using this font.

Where did you get that font from? Do you know who created it? If yes, maybe these errors mean something to him and he can fix the font? Once you get to install it correctly on Mac OS, chances are higher that it will also work on iOS, I guess.

Comment: I have FontCreator and I can change it , as long as I know what to change. How did you get these errors? How did you try to install it?

Comment: Just double-clicked it in Finder.app. After that it opens Font Book, having a "Install Font" button in the lower right corner. Once I click that, I get the detailed error screen: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1365846/ez.ttf.png

Comment: It does not open in Font Book, (OSX Mountain Lion), but I 'll take a look at the error screen.

Comment: I found the errors, let me check them and I will be back later.