# Custom Font not working in Swift/Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, fonts

I have a problem with a custom font in my project. I tried both ways: by code and interface builder.

I added TeamSpiritNF.ttf to the project and added it to the info.plist (Fonts provided by application).

Then in the code I entered this:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "TeamSpiritNF", size: 30)!]
```

When entering the screen in the simulator the App crashes:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

But the same line works fine if I change the font name to Helvetica for example.

And if I use this font for a label in the interface builder (where I can select it from the dropdown), it is shown correct in the preview. But when I run the application in the simulator entering that screen is delayed and the label uses Helvetica Neue instead of TeamSpiritNF.

Anyone has an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't use custom font in iOS app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053597/cant-use-custom-font-in-ios-app)

Comment: The referenced question has several answers that lay out exactly what you need to do to use custom fonts in an iOS application.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Create a new folder in your project directory and move your custom fonts there.
2. In the left sidebar, select your target, then *Build Phases* and you should see *Copy Bundle Resources*.
3. Make sure your fonts are included in the list. If they aren't, include them by clicking on the <kbd>+</kbd> button.

Comment: Solution didn't worked for me still getting the same error fatal "error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Are you specifing the name of the font via code, right? If so, probably you probably got the name of the font wrong.

Comment: i have copy pasted the font name. They are working fine when i use the same font via storyboard

Answer (score 7):

1. Make sure your fonts are in info.plist (Fonts provided by application)
2. Select yor target, in the build phases tab, Copy Bundle Resources, add your fonts.

Comment: my fonts were working fine, but after i tried to clean osx fonts cache, it stopped working. adding this made things go back to normal for whatever reason.